# OpenMP Matrix-Vector Multiplication Executes on Only One Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, mex

I have this code (outlined below) for parallelizing matrix-vector multiplication. But whenever I run it, I discover that it is executing on just one thread (even though I specified 4). How can I separate parts of the parallel code to run on separate threads. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
int nthreads;
nthreads = 4;    
omp_set_num_threads(nthreads);
chunk = m/nthreads;

  #pragma omp parallel for private(i,j,H) schedule(static,chunk)
  for (i=0; i<m; i++ ){ 
    C[i]=0;
     for (j=0; j<p; j++) {
       int H = omp_get_thread_num();
       C[i] += (A[i+(j*m)]*B[j]);
   }              
 }
```

Comment: could you additionally provide your numbers for `m` and `chunk`

Comment: Hi @Henkersmann m is the number of rows of the matrix A, like 20. While chunk is (m/number-of-threads), which would be 5 if I set number of threads to 4. I've updated the code to reflect this.

Comment: Note that `schedule(static)` defaults to the chunk size being `#iterations / #threads`, so you don't have to explicitly provide `chunk`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you include this snippet in `#pragma omp parallel{...}` or you might be missing the word `parallel`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the number of threads. You can do it using the OMP_NUM_THREADS environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're compiling with Openmp enabled ? Your compiler should throw an error if so since your variable `H` has been declared within the scope of the parallel region holding the `private(i, j, H)` clause .

Depending on you compiler, you should add the corresponding OpenMp flag , `-fopenmp` for gcc for example. 
You can also check the number of available threads at runtime by calling `omp_get_num_threads()`.